# Selenium clicking of Lightning Elements causing abnormal behavior

Tags: lightning, selenium

I'm using Selenium to click the "View All" link in the App Builder drop down:

```
const element = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(`//lightning-button[.="View All"]`)), 5000);
await element.click();
```

[image]

This causes the App Launcher modal to do this:

[image]

I put those boxes there to hide our apps. Anyway the spinner never goes away. Of course when I go click it as a human everything works fine. I saw something similar when clicking "Save" on an Edit Case modal. It would show a toast and Save like everything was working perfectly but the field wouldn't update.

My guess is this is some kind of Salesforce security feature. Is anyone aware of an issue with selenium clicking standard Salesforce elements ?

The last problem with the Case modal was only happening when using the driver to execute a script click() `arguments[0].click()` but this App Launcher problem is happening with standard Selenium click() method too.

I thought it could be something with the shadow-dom. I tried clicking the outermost element possible which was a `<lightning-button></lightning-button>` but that didn't help. The whole thing is withing a `<one-app-launcher-menu></one-app-launcher-menu>`

What I'm going to do now is go see if this is a standard lwc I can look into.

Please let me know if you're aware of any possible causes.